# Dynamically import in python through a Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I need to import modules using a dictionary, I would like to loop through the dictionary and import it. For example

```
items = {
    'Initial_Load': 'initial_load',
    'Disclaimer': 'disclaimer_tests',
    'Menu': 'menu_tests'
}
```

Those items should convert into

```
from Inital_Load import initial_load
from Disclaimer import disclaimer_tests
from Menu import menu_tests
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) to import the module, then `getattr` to resolve the name from that modules namespace:

```
from importlib import import_module

def import_dict(d):
    result = {}
    for module_name, attr_name in d.items():
        module = import_module(module_name)
        result[attr_name] = getattr(module, attr_name)
    return result

import_dict({"math": "sqrt"})["sqrt"](4)
# 2.0
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked out great. Thank you